# What's the different between url-pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC .

To configure servlet mapping in web.xml.

**Who can tell what's difference between them**

```
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login/</url-pattern>

<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>

<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
```

Maybe more...

It is really necessary for me to know ,so that a new servlet will not be Intercept by other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
```

This is exact url pattern, this servlet will be invoked only if the url is like `someThing.com/login`

```
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

This is directory url pattern. So `/someString` or `/someOtherString` or `/some/someOther` will invoke the same `login` servlet.

```
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
```

This is extension url pattern. Anything that is suffixed as `.do` will map to this. e.g. `/someUrl.do` or `/some/someOther.do` will invoke the `login` servlet.

Comment: Give a example of request that distinguish ( /*  and  /  ) , thanks

Comment: I am not very sure about the distinction between /* and / to be frank so did not give an example for the same. Maybe @Kevin will explain it.

Comment: @karlli / just maps the root, /* maps everything - asterix is a wildcard.

Answer (score -1):

this looks rather strange,you have this

```
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

and thats all you need, the rest of the mapping are supercilious. But calling your spring servlet login is a bit weird.  Normally you would call it spring-servlet or similar, everything is then mapped to that servlet, and specific request mappings are handled by different controllers - you can use RequestMappign annoation on controller methods.